# If $f\geq 0$ measurable and $(\varphi _n)$ is a sequence of simple function that converges increasingly to $f$, can such a sequence be non-negative?

Tags: measure-theory

In the Book of Stein and Shakarchi (real analysis), we have the following theorem:

> Suppose $f$ is a non-negative measurable function on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{\varphi_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that satisfies:
>   $$\varphi_k(x) \leq \varphi_{k+1}(x) \space\space\text{ and }\space\space \lim_{k\to\infty} \varphi_k(x)=f(x) \text{ for all x}$$
>   In general, if $f$ is only measurable, there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{\varphi_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that satisfies
>   $$|\varphi_k(x)| \leq |\varphi_{k+1}(x)| \space\space\text{ and }\space\space 
> \lim_{k\to\infty} \varphi_k(x)=f(x) \text{ for all x}$$

When $X=\mathbb R$, $\mathcal M$ the Lebesgue measurable set and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, then such a sequence can be taken non-negative. But here it's not mention. Does it mean that such non-negative sequence may not exist ? If yes, could someone provide an example ?

Comment: Any nonnegative measurable function is the pointwise limit of a sequence of nonnegative simple functions.

Comment: What does the "But here it's not mention." refer to?

Comment: @Hume2: That the $\varphi _n$ are non negative.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: So I can add the fact that $\varphi _n$ are non negative ?

Comment: If some $\varphi_n$ are sometimes negative, replace by $\max\{0,\varphi_n(x)\}$, which is still a simple function.  Or are you worried that some $\varphi_n$ may be complex?

Comment: @GEdgar: but then it won't be increasing, no ?

Comment: Yes: If $\varphi_n$ is increasing, then so is $\max\{0,\varphi_n\}$

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. If you start by $\varphi_1=0$, then all next functions must be non-negative.

Some of the $\varphi_k$ functions might be (partially) negative but all points must converge to non-negative values.